# How does getCurrencyInstance in java works

Tags: java, locale, numberformatter

I need to convert a given number to rupee. For that I used the following `NumberFormat` class.

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat. getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "IN")) ;
```

How does Java map "Rs." Format to "IN" country that we entered? Is it the work of `getCurrencyInstance` or Locale class and where does Java look for it?

Comment: You find the answer in the documentation for the [Currency class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html)